# Not able to perform any gesture over a JButton (using Leap Motion)

Tags: java, swing, leap-motion

I am working with Jframes and jpanels to create a simulator.
I have used this code snippet for the calculation of dot position on the application window:

```
Screen screen = controller.locatedScreens().get(0);

    int handsCount = frame.hands().count();
    if(handsCount == 1)
    {
        Hand hand = frame.hands().get(0);
        int fingerCount = hand.fingers().count();
        Point2D.Float normPt = calcScreenNorm(hand, screen);
        if (fingerCount == 1)   // one finger == move point
            doodle.movePoint(normPt);
    }

}

private Point2D.Float calcScreenNorm(Hand hand, Screen screen)


  /* The dot position is calculated using the screen position that the
     user's hand is pointing at, which is then normalized to an (x,y)
     value between -1 and 1, where (0,0) is the center of the screen.
  */

  {
    Vector palm = hand.palmPosition();
    Vector direction = hand.direction();
    Vector intersect = screen.intersect(palm, direction, true);
          // intersection is in screen coordinates

    // test for NaN (not-a-number) result of intersection
    if (Float.isNaN(intersect.getX()) || Float.isNaN(intersect.getY()))
      return null;

    float xNorm = (Math.min(1, Math.max(0, intersect.getX())) - 0.5f)*2;      // constrain to -1 -- 1
    float yNorm = (Math.min(1, Math.max(0, (1-intersect.getY()))) - 0.5f)*2; 

    return new Point2D.Float(xNorm, yNorm);
  }  // end of calcScreenNorm()
I have got the point (orange dot) on the application window and i have created a jbutton (black) on the panel too.
```

Now when i move my finger (and so the point moves on the window), the point is coming beneath the button. Thus, i am not able to apply my screen tap gesture on the button.

Please help me out in this regard.
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried intersecting the point with the button and firing a onclick programatically

Comment: @epoch No, i haven't tried with the intersection. Will it be by using ActionListener class? if so, could you please help me out with that.

Comment: not really sure on how to use it..will be grateful if i can receive any help on that :)

Comment: @epoch i think intersection is the problem here, because when i move my finger in then application window, the point instead of hovering on top of the button, hovers underneath it. So, firing an onCLick will it work unless the point is on top of the button? ..Please do correct me if i am wrong..Thanks!

Comment: The components, namely jbutton and the point is getting overlapped on the same jpanel. 
 
Is there any way i can make the point to be always on top? 

Thanks in advance!